# finding a line that contains… etc

Tags: c#

Ok, well i'm basically trying to find a certain line withing "Users.txt"

Heres my code so far.

```
if (ok == "b" || ok == "B")
    {
    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("Users.txt"))
        {
            //Test
            Out.WriteLine("Please state the username");
            string user = Console.ReadLine();
            Out.WriteLine("Checking..");
            if (w.Equals(user))
            {
                Out.WriteLine("Username is taken");
            }
            Thread.Sleep(pause);
            Out.WriteLine("Please state the password for the user");
            string pass = Console.ReadLine();
            Logger(user, pass, w);
            // Close the writer and underlying file.
            w.Close();
            Out.WriteLine("Checking..");
            Out.WriteBlank();
            Thread.Sleep(pause);
            Out.WriteLine("Anything else Mr." + Environment.UserName + " ?");
        }
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();

            if (choice == "no")
            {
                Boot();
            }
            if (choice == "yes")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Title = "Administrator Panel";
                Panel();
            }
        }
```

want it to see if the "user" is taken, then stop them from executing the process.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: w.Equals is actually comparing the StreamWriter with the string 'user', which will always return false. Also, you should be using StreamReader, not StreamWriter. I can't give the exact code at the moment, don't have VS/LinqPad installed on this computer, but it would be something along the lines of while(!reader.EOF) { reader.ReadLine; Compare line with users, etc}

Answer (score 2):

Try reading (`StreamReader` with `File.Open`) each existing username into an array/List and then comparing user input against that list.

Your current code doesn't actually read anything since you're using a `StreamWriter` with `File.AppendText` which just lets you write to the end of a file.

**Examples**:

[Reading File into a List](http://www.dotnetperls.com/readline)

```
List<string> users = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Users.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        users.Add(line);
    }
}

...

string user = Console.ReadLine();
Out.WriteLine("Checking..");
if (users.Contains(user))
{
    Out.WriteLine("Username is taken");
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit of a learner, Could you maybe show me an example of what your talking about?

Comment: @Dev-Studios - A `StreamWriter` writes to a file. You want to read from a file, so you need a `StreamReader`.

Comment: **Suggestion**:  After you get this functionality working, search around for best practices on what you're trying to achieve (reading input from console, etc) and then refactor your code with what you've learned.

Comment: I'd actually be doing the compare for each line (rather than at the end against an array/list). If the function is being called multiple times, then I'd a) check the existing read user names. b) If not found, keep reading and comparing (and then storing in list), rather than reading the entire file and doing a compare. Edit: A hashset would also probably be better to store the user names

Comment: @Rob:  A) That's extremely nit-picky considering we can't see any context of this code at all.  B) I'm not about to write a fault-tolerant whisper-clean super-efficient implementation of the code for the submitter, that's his job.

Comment: I wasn't attacking you, I even gave +1. Was just adding a suggestion for an improvement

Comment: If a 10 year old wants to learn how to build a doghouse do you hand her a nail gun before she knows how to use a hammer?

Comment: I fail to see how checking each line, rather than adding to a list and doing a check at the end is more complex.

Answer (score 1):

There are various problems with your code. Let's see if we can break it down one piece at a time.

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("Users.txt"))
```

This code would be useful if you wanted to open "Users.txt" and append text to it. Since you want to open a file and read from it, you need to use a different object, the `StreamReader` object:

```
using (StreamReader r = File.Open("Users.txt"))
```

Next, you want to check if the given Username is in the file. You're doing:

```
if (w.Equals(user))
{
    Out.WriteLine("Username is taken");
}
```

This isn't going to work. You are comparing a `StreamWriter` object with a `String` object. They will never be equal.

What you need to do instead is change the order of your program like this:

First, read the entire contents of the file into memory. Then, outside of the `Using` statement, process your user input and your username/password checking.

Let's assume the file is organized like this:

```
username,password
username2,password2
johnsmith,mysecretcode
janedoe,blahblah
```

You could, for example, read each line into a `Dictionary` object, where the `Key` is the username and the `Value` is the password.

```
Dictionary<String, String> myDictionary = new Dictionary<String, String>
// Example of adding ONE username/password to the dictionary
myDictionary.Add("username", "password");
```

Then, checking for the username would be as simple as

```
bool containsUsername = myDictionary.ContainsKey(username);
```

And checking the password would be:

```
bool doesPasswordMatch = myDictionary[username] == givenPassword;
```

Give it a shot! C# is a great language to learn.